# How is the data in /proc/* gathered, and how reliable is it?

Tags: linux, proc

Recently I've been working with a cluster monitoring tool (ganglia) which aggregates system metrics from `/proc/*` on each machine.

1. How is the data in `/proc/*` gathered?
   Who writes the data there? How often is the data updated?
2. Can I tune the way it is gathered so that it is more accurate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

> /proc is very special in that it is also a virtual filesystem. It's
>   sometimes referred to as a process information pseudo-file system. It
>   doesn't contain 'real' files but runtime system information (e.g.
>   system memory, devices mounted, hardware configuration, etc). For this
>   reason it can be regarded as a control and information centre for the
>   kernel. In fact, quite a lot of system utilities are simply calls to
>   files in this directory. For example, 'lsmod' is the same as 'cat
>   /proc/modules' while 'lspci' is a synonym for 'cat /proc/pci'. By
>   altering files located in this directory you can even read/change
>   kernel parameters (sysctl) while the system is running.

In other words, this is real-time information directly from the kernel/etc, not files that are periodically updated.

Comment: The answer is good, however it has a good basis and potential to be much more elaborate. I will leave as a sugestion to extend it a little more with how changing proc variables affects the system, how sysctl works, and provide a link.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro While I agree there is a great deal more information that one can learn about `/proc/`, a full in-depth explanation of `/proc/` was not the question, and a link that expands *greatly* on the subject was included.

Comment: Somehow the link escaped me, thanks. The point of expanding the answer is your choice, more expanded answers usually get more points from others. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The data in `/proc` is not updated at all.  It is generated on demand.

When you read from `/proc` (or indeed from any file at all), you are calling into the kernel.  If you're reading a "real" file, the kernel will then (subject to caching, permissions, etc.) traverse the filesystem and retrieve the data you requested.  If you're reading a `/proc` "file," the kernel will generate the relevant data on the fly.

This technique has become rather popular, and is now widely used in different areas of the filesystem.  For instance, the [`/sys` virtual filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) is very similar to `/proc` from an architectural standpoint, though the contents are entirely different.  On modern systems, you may find that `/dev` is also [a virtual filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), since it is otherwise rather painful to keep the files in `/dev` up-to-date with hardware realities.  Some userland services provide their own virtual filesystems through [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace).

Answer (score 0):

The files in `/proc` are mostly implemented as device drivers. They're basically implemented in a similar way to serial devices (`/dev/ttyS*`) except that instead of returning data from hardware the programmer returns data generated by his program.

In a way, it's similar to a web server. Only, instead of listening to a tcp socket and responding, `/proc` files are devices drivers that listen for read requests and responding.

There is nothing in the design of Unix kernel drivers that forces device nodes to only be mounted in `/dev` therefore people took the opportunity to develop and standardize the `/proc` directory to contain virtual devices that return some run-time information. These days the Linux kernel includes dedicated methods to handle `/proc` drivers.

Here's an article about devices drivers that includes an example of a `/proc` driver: http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/07/05/devhelloworld-a-simple-introduction-to-device-drivers-under-linux.html